# Conditional task scheduling - multi-threaded Java application

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a multi-threaded Java application containing a 'resource manager' class.

This class is supplied a list of resources that may be requested as an initialization parameter. It then checks the local file system for each file and adds those determined to be local to a list.

When the class receives a resource request one of the following occurs:

1. If a resource is determined to be local (in the list): Provide the URI where it can be found.
2. If the resource is remote (not in the list): Schedule a worker to acquire the resource. The worker will notify the manager when the task completes, and the local resource list will be updated. (Requesting Threads don't wait - either its there or its not).

As multiple threads can request resources a ReadWriteLock is used to coordinate list access. Many threads can read the list concurrently, and when an update is necessary the writeLock will be used.

The issue is with scheduling the background worker for any particular remote resource. If multiple threads schedule workers for the **same** resource then unnecessary overhead is required (even if duplicate tasks do not execute completely because they check for this case). In order to achieve the highest efficiency possible I'm wondering about the following implementation:

```
private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

//assume each resource object has a volatile boolean "scheduled"
//with isScheduled() and setSheduled() setter/getter;

//assume the resource list is thread safe

public URI requestResource(Resource theResource){
  URI resourceId = null;
  //many threads can enter here 
  lock.readLock().lock();
  try{
    //if our resource is not in the list
    if(!localResouces.contains(theResource)){
       //double-check idiom...does it work here?
       //if the resource isn't scheduled
       if(!theResource.isScheduled()){
          //only one thread may enter here
          synchronized(this){
            if(!theResource.isScheduled()){
               //schedule task here...
               theResource.setScheduled(true);                                      
            }
          }  
       }
    } else {
       //its local, return the location
       resouceId = theResource.getURI();
    }
  } finally {
    lock.readLock().unlock();
  }
//requesting object will deal with null value;
return resouceId;
}
```

and when the worker is finished:

```
public void update(Resource theResource){
  //ensures no threads in the read block
  lock.writeLock().lock();
  try {
      //update the list (would check result IRL, and not add if problem found)
      localResources.add(theResource);
      //set the scheduled field
      theResource.setScheduled(false); 
  } finally {
       lock.writeLock().unlock();
  }
}
```

Again, I would like to maximize efficiency. I could not find an example matching this case - i.e. Allow high throughput for common operations while allowing the task to be scheduled with minimal blocking/overhead.

What are the problems with this approach? The first method must both obtain the read lock and synchronize however the update method only needs to obtain the write lock because the check for isScheduled is encapsulated within the read block. Does this provide thread safe scheduling and data access?

EDIT:

Ive tested the method described above and I am seeing the correct behavior. I'm still unsure if this is actually 'thread-safe.'

Comment: why do you need a list for local resources? why not have a flag in `Resource` to indicate it's local?

Comment: My goal is to reduce the entrance into synchronized blocks as much as possible. Could you elaborate on how this suggestion would help move toward that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do it this way:

```
class Resource

    Uri localUri;
    volatile int state; // REMOTE, FETCHING, LOCAL

    Resource()
        if local
            localUri = ...;
            state = LOCAL;
        else
            state = REMOTE

    URI requestResource()

        if(state==LOCAL)  // volatile read
            return localUri;
        if(state==FETCHING)
            return null;

        synchronized(lock)
            if(state==LOCAL)
                return localUri;
            if(state==FETCHING)
                return null;

            // REMOTE, and it's my job to initiate fetching
            state=FETCHING;
            // do actaul fetching outside synchronized block

        schedule fetching...

    void onFetchingDone()

        synchronized(lock)

            if error
                state=REMOTE; // to retry.
                // if we consider error unrecoverable,
                // we need an ERROR state.
            else
                ...
                loalUri = ...;
                state = LOCAL;  // volatile write
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on the efficiency of these operations, but this doesn't seem the most appropriate solution. Each request must at minimum preform a volatile read. Additionally if a Resource 'x' was remote every thread requesting it would need to enter the synchronized block (to check if a worker had been dispatched) until the worker generated by the first request had returned.

Comment: a volatile read is a lot cheaper than entering a read lock. On your 2nd point, I added one more checking outside synchronized block. the code can be further optimized which I'll do in a short while.